# Format Json Responses as Camel Case

Tags: 8, page-controller

Currently our json responses are not formatted at all, we are using the `JsonResponse` class to return a status code with content:

```
  public function getMarkets() {
    $response = $this->marketService->getMarkets();

    return new JsonResponse($response, 200);
  }
```

Is there an easy way to make sure all json responses are formatted as camel case or do we have to make sure the properties are camelcased before passing them to the JsonResponse object?

Comment: What is getMarkets returning? Are you using the Serializer service to format it’s response? See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html

Comment: getMarkets is just returning an array of objects and we aren't formatting it in the service at all, I was wondering if there was a way to format all outgoing responses without doing it manually for every call

Comment: Without looking at the code I think JsonResponse ensures the returned HTTP response is proper, but won’t auto convert your data structure the way you want it.

Comment: what would you say is the best way to handle that then? We were thinking about extending the JsonResponse class and then having it returned a camel case response

Comment: Drupal convention for properties is to use snake case so if you have a contradictory opinion forcing your hand at API design, then you'll need to redo things (I had to do this in Services in Drupal 7 because someone couldn't handle, opinion-wise, "field_" on properties). I guess, if you're not relying on serialization module, then making your own JsonResponse would be fine. I don't think this is worth it and it would increase the cognitive load for anyone learning the site code base.

Comment: Additionally, working around Drupal properties means that if you take in data you'd need some way to map back into the real properties, which gets complex quickly when dealing with large data sets. That could be alleviated by making leaner services though.

Comment: I understand that drupal property convetion is snake case, but I'm talking about the JSON response sent to the front end, most languages/frameworks have a very easy to way to convert the payload to camel case and back to snake case, also javascript naming convetions is camel case so which is why we typically use a serializer